# Which intoxicants and relaxants are not forbidden?

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, sunni

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/115761

> narrated by Ahmad in his Musnad and by Abu Dawood in his Sunan with a
>   saheeh isnaad from Umm Salamah (may Allaah be pleased with him) who
>   said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) forbade **all kinds of** intoxicants and relaxants.

That **all kinds of** bit seems to tell me that many different types of intoxicants and relaxants were forbidden but not all.  If it had said **forbade ALL intoxicants and relaxants**, that to mean would mean that absolutely ALL intoxicants and relaxants are forbidden.  But the above hadith says **all kinds of** instead of **all**.

I say this because according to the dictionary, **all kinds of** roughly means the same thing as **all manner of** or **all sorts of**:

Source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/all+kinds+of

> **All kinds of**: also, all manner or  sorts of .  All or many varieties of something, as in Before the banquet, they served all
>   kinds of drinks , or He sold exotic fruit of all sorts , or The museum
>   featured all manner of artifacts . [Early 1300s]

So my question is, if all relaxants and intoxicants are not forbidden, which types are not forbidden?  i.e. which relaxants and intoxicants were not forbidden by the prophet of islam and/or God when the prophet of islam was alive?

Here are some definitions from Google search:

> **Intoxicanting**: Cause (someone) to lose control of their faculties or
>   behavior.
>
> **Relaxants**: A drug used to promote relaxation or reduce tension.
>
> **Languor**: The state or feeling, often pleasant, of tiredness or inertia
>
> **Ineria**: A tendency to do nothing or to remain unchanged

Comment: You may also want to post this on the English/Language SE website. I do think that `all kinds of` means `all of`. Logically, it's saying `for every kind of intoxicant` => `for all intoxicants of any kind`

Answer (score 2):

There are two general criteria Intoxicant/Relaxants:

1. It should not cause a person loose the ability to judge right from wrong.
2. It should not cause addiction, such that if not taken, will drastically effect a person's ability to do daily activities.

For example, tea/coffee does enhance mental ability but it is not addictive. People go about doing their daily activities during Ramazan without a cup of coffee in the morning.

It is also known that different quantities of these kinds of drugs effect every person to a different degree. Thus it is very difficult to defined a "permissible" quantity. A general rule given by scholars is "if a large quantity causes a person to loose control over oneself, then smaller quantity of that is also forbidden".

Based on this reasoning, alcohol is forbidden, although for someone, taking a sip will not effect him in any way.

Comment: This might be slightly off topic, but according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine_addiction caffeine can be 1. addictive and 2. intoxicating in large quantities.  2 points which you mentioned in your answer.  So based on your answer, tea seems to fit in your criteria of forbidden intoxicants...  But this is offtopic.  I am more interested in which intoxicants relaxants which were not forbidden when the prophet of islam was alive.

Comment: If new research in science proves something to be harmful, then it becomes prohibited. Its where religious and scientific community should collaborate with each other. Personally, I think there is more work to be done by the religious scholars to give a clear criteria about this. Till then each one of us should use his own best judgement.

Comment: That makes sence.  Also, I'm wondering if the wording issue I described above as in "all kinds of" is a translation issue?  Anyone here know arabic who can check if the hadith above has been translated appropriately?